# Why do I have to distribute my CA signed code signing certificate with GPO?

Tags: wsus, pki

I have an enterprise PKI. My issuing CA is part of my Active Directory.

For the Windows Package Publisher I issued a code signing certificate, which should normally be valid inside my whole AD structure (it is signed by my issuing CA). Still I have to import the code signing certificate for every computer where I want to deploy third party updates with WPP.

Any ideas why WSUS won't trust the WPP packages if the code signing certificate is not locally imported on the local computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement is documented in [Setting Up The Trust Relationship](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb902479(v=vs.85)) and elsewhere.  The key point is that the specific code signing certificate used by third-party WSUS packages has to be in the Trusted Publishers store, it isn't just a matter of the packages being signed by *any* valid certificate.

Note in particular the following paragraph:

> **Important** Enabling local publishing has security implications; your update clients and servers will now trust code signed with the certificate above. For security reasons, if you choose to enable local publishing, we strongly recommend that you restrict access to the private key of the code signing certificate and that you configure your update server to use SSL for all communications.

Basically, if the Windows Update client accepted packages with any valid certificate, the clients would be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks against your WSUS server, or against Windows Update itself.  By default, only packages signed by Microsoft are accepted.  You need to tell your clients that they also need to accept packages that you have signed, which you do by importing that specific certificate into the Trusted Publishers store.

Note that in an enterprise PKI scenario, the root certificate is typically automatically exported to the clients via group policy, but this just gives it the same level of trust as any other recognized certificate authority.  Windows doesn't treat certificates issued by your CA any differently to other certificates.